# how to add css styling inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually i am using iframe element in html page but it is inside  tag which means javascript. so I want to add css to that iframe element, how can I do that? Can someone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles from the parent will not be applied to the document within the iframe. The best solution is to add the stylesheet to the document in the iframe. Either via javascript or creating a template page to load in via src. 
Something like:

```js
var head = doc.head
var link = doc.createElement('link')
link.type = 'text/css'
link.rel = 'stylesheet'
link.href = ...src...
head.appendChild(link)
```

This is an example: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoVzPa)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourElement.style.attribute = value
```

for example

```
var button = document.getElementById("btn")
button.style.color = "red"
button.style.marginTop = 0;
```

when writing css in javascript you must use camel case css for example type `marginTop` not type the `margin-top`